# Android: I can't seem to get my custom toolbar's back arrow to act like the device's physical back arrow

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I have the back arrow implimented and working but instead of just finishing the activityB and going back to the previous view (fragment) the user was on in activityA. It instead closes activityB and reloads activityA which means you have to go back through a few menus to get back to where you were.

The physical back arrow does exactly as I want it to in that it just closes the activtyB and puts the user back to where they were within activtyA originally before they moved to activtyB.

This is my current code for the toolbar back arrow but maybe I'm just not fully grasping how the physical back arrow works. I appreciate any and all advice!

```
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to override the onOptionsItemSelected method of your activity:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
    if (menuItem.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        onBackPressed();
    } else {
        super.onOptionsItemSelected(menuItem);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: This worked exactly as I wanted it to and it was a super simple fix. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For every activity you have to add parent activity in Android manifest file.

```
    <activity
      android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.ActivityC"
      android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message"
      android:parentActivityName="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" >
      <!-- The meta-data element is needed for versions lower than 4.1 -->
      <meta-data
         android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
         android:value="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
```

If you specified MainActivity as parent to ActivityC then it will go to MainActivity. If you specified ActivityB it will move to ActivityB on click on back button in ActionBar.

For more see at [here](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal.html)

Comment: That makes sense thanks and I learned something new today. This would probably fix my issue if I had been using only activities. I just realized I forgot to mention that ActivityA uses fragments (as I have never used them before and this project is for me to learn as much new stuff as i can) so I needed the back arrow to return to activityA with its last fragment showing. Sorry I wasn't thorough with my initial inquiry, but thanks for teaching me something new! I didn't fully understand parent activities until that link.